# Software after formatting to download what you need/want

Tags: download-manager, installer

I often have to format computers. Actually I bring with me a pen drive with the installers of the software I use. But the main problem is that they aren't updated. So I was looking for a software where I can setup a list of what I want and then it downloads the latest version of it and possibly it installs it too automatically.

I've Google it without results. And if it's a duplicate, could you link me the other post?

Comment: I believe these two question are relevant: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1133/6834 and http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10041/6834 . Check if the answers there might apply to your case

Comment: The solution has to run on … Microsoft Windows?

Comment: I work with windows and linux os. So if you find something on any of this os  just tell me.

Comment: Have you seen this yet? https://ninite.com There's a limited amount of software,  but it's a start.

Comment: I was on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/windows-program-to-show-available-updates-for-all-programs-on-computer and one of the responses was PatchMyPC.  https://patchmypc.net/download
It seems to be good. and npackd might be worth checking out http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/npackd/

Comment: If you want remote management try https://www.lumension.com/ , but it cost money.  However, then you can update the computers without visiting them.  You can integrate patches into the installer file for Windows with built-in tools like dism.

Comment: Ninite seems what I was looking for. But as hhaslam said there are only a few softwares in it. cybernard I'll check yours now

Comment: If you mean that the software you're installing is often out of date then I would recommend https://ninite.com/ It lets you create one downloadable exe, which will chain download and install (silently) a whole bunch of apps (using the most up to date installers) from one place. Internet connection required at runtime, though